# Tips about checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am new to CheckStyle and I don't have any good idea for some situations.

## Example 1

```
 void loadThumbnail(Context context, int resize, Drawable placeholder, ImageView imageView, Uri uri);
```

As you see, the method's length is too long.So I use :

```
     <module name="LineLength">
       <property name="max" value="100"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodLength">
        <property name="max" value="140"/>
    </module>
```

It seems that `MethodLength` is covered by `LineLength`

## Example 2

When I put a link into comment such as:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/MediaFile.java

Obviously this link is too long.How can I deal with it?

Comment: 1: you reformat the method declaration so that it fits into your limit. 2. you ignore the warning, because you have no other reasonable choice.

Comment: @JBNizet 2.I think short URL is useful.

Comment: You can do that, too, although you're losing information about what the link actually refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great that you are looking into Checkstyle! It's a nice tool for many tasks, although far from perfect and by no means a solution for everything.

About the [LineLength](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html#LineLength) and [MethodLength](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html#MethodLength) checks: These actually check two very different things:

- *LineLength* checks the actual length of a line of text in your file
- *MethodLength* checks the number of lines in a method (yes, lines, not statements, that's what [ExecutableStatementCount](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html#ExecutableStatementCount) is for)

So you would normally enable both *LineLength* and *MethodLength* (or *ExecutableStatementCount*, which I prefer over *MethodLength*).

*LineLength* must be configured to handle long lines which cannot be made any shorter, such as your link example. Recent versions of Checkstyle handle `package` and `import` statements by default. The check also features an `ignorePattern` that you can set to filter out other long lines. The documentation gives this example:

```xml
<module name="LineLength">
   <property name="ignorePattern" value="^ *\* *[^ ]+$"/>
</module>
```

In this example, lines where a Javadoc contains only one word (here, meaning no spaces except right after the asterisk), will not be flagged regardless of their length. In this way, you should be able to cover most of your cases.

Comment: Your explain about `MethodLength` is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using IDEs like eclipse you can use formatting to help you with line wrapping. To satisfy CheckStyle line length.
2. MethodLength CheckStyle is asking you to look at the method and refactor into smaller methods which has one task to perform.